# Ambiguous column name when putting together several nested SELECT statements

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to use a snippet of code from https://gist.github.com/fhoffa/411cd5ac0d7b8bd2b17a.

Getting this error message:
Column name c1 is ambiguous at [1:24]

```sql
SELECT 'c1' AS column, c1 AS value, rowid
FROM
    (SELECT 1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3, 'id1' rowid),
    (SELECT 9 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3, 'id2' rowid), 
    (SELECT 4 c1, 1 c2, 3 c3, 'id3' rowid)
```

This code was posted 8 years ago.
It may have worked at that time but it is not working now.

I appreciate any feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using 'UNION ALL' got rid of the error.
Also, there must be an extra parenthesis needed to
group these 3 select statements.
Without the parenthesis, a misleading error message shows up:
Something like first select has 3 columns but the second select has
4 columns.  Weird error message.

```sql
SELECT 'c1' AS column, c1 as value, rowid

FROM

    (
     (SELECT 1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3, 'id1' as rowid)
     UNION ALL
     (SELECT 9 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3, 'id2' as rowid)
     UNION ALL
     (SELECT 4 c1, 1 c2, 3 c3, 'id3' as rowid)
    )
```

[image]